# Email ASP.NET webpage with Chart Controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mschart, stringbuilder

I have an asp.net 4.0 webpage which has 10 chart controls on it. I have been to email the chart controls to the current logged in user when they open the page. The chart controls will be different for each user. I have been testing this by trying to send 1 chart control but the body of the email doesnt show the chart only the image outline. I have tried several things but cant get it to work. The code i have just now is -

web.config

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=memory;deleteAfterServicing=true;"/>
```

webpage

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    SendMail()

End Sub

Private Sub SendMail()

    Dim SB As New StringBuilder()
    Dim SW As New StringWriter(SB)
    Dim htmlTW As New HtmlTextWriter(SW)
    'SB.Append("<td><img src=""cid:chart17""></td>")
    Chart10.RenderControl(htmlTW)
    Dim MyHTML As String = SB.ToString()

    Dim from As String = "EMAIL ADDRESS"
    Dim recip As String = "EMAIL ADDRESS"
    'Dim recip As String = Membership.GetUser.Email.ToString
    Dim subject As String = "Test Email"




    'Create message object and populate w/ data from form
    Dim message As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
    message.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from.Trim())
    message.To.Add(recip.Trim())
    message.Subject = subject.Trim()
    message.IsBodyHtml = True
    message.Body = MyHTML
    'Setup SmtpClient to send email. Uses web.config settings.
    Dim smtpClient As System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient = New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()

    'Error handling for sending message
    Try
        smtpClient.Send(message)
        'Exception contains information on each failed receipient
    Catch recExc As System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientsException
        For recipient = 0 To recExc.InnerExceptions.Length - 1
            Dim statusCode As System.Net.Mail.SmtpStatusCode
            'Each InnerException is an System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailed RecipientException
            statusCode = recExc.InnerExceptions(recipient).StatusCode

            If (statusCode = Net.Mail.SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy) Or (statusCode = Net.Mail.SmtpStatusCode.MailboxUnavailable) Then
                'Log this to event log: recExc.InnerExceptions(recipient).FailedRecipient
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
                smtpClient.Send(message)
            Else
                'Log error to event log.
                'recExc.InnerExceptions(recipient).StatusCode or use statusCode
            End If

        Next
        'General SMTP execptions
    Catch smtpExc As System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
        'Log error to event log using StatusCode information in
        'smtpExc.StatusCode
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Log error to event log.
    End Try

End Sub
```

As you can see i have tried some examples on forums like "SB.Append" and "chart10.rendercontrol(htmlTW) but both do not work for me.

Any helpo would be greatful.

Answer (score 1):

You are not attaching the image to the e-mail.

```
''I am not sure how to handle memory streams in vb but it should be something like so.
Dim ms as MemoryStream = new MemoryStream()
Chart10.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png)
Dim A As System.Net.Mail.Attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, "MyChart.png")
A.ContentId = "chart17"
A.ContentDisposition.Inline = True
message.Attachments.Add(A)
```